# Feed automatic input to PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script (.ps1), which asks for multiple user inputs. I want to input the answers automatically, so far I found a way to input only to first prompt, and the script hangs at second prompt. The below will feed "123" to only 1st prompt. How can I modify this to feed input to second prompt as well.

```
cmd /c echo 123 | powershell "C:\temp\Snap.ps1"
```

Script (it takes two inputs `$CONumber` and `$CSV`):

```
$CONumber = Read-Host "Enter the CO Number"


$CSV =  Read-Host "Full path to the CSV file"
```

Comment: You should re-write your script to accept command-line parameters, rather than prompting the user.

Comment: Yeah, definitely sounds like you want to re-design that script, maybe post the contents (or an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))?

Comment: Added script snippet, which takes two inputs $CONumber and $CSV

Comment: As others have mentioned before, you want to re-design your script so that you can provide input via [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters).

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you need to rewrite the script to not use Read-Host and instead accept the parameters at the command line. Fortunately, this is easy. Just add the following line at the top of the script:

```
param($CONumber, $CSV)
```

and remove the two lines you quoted above. You can then call the script like so:

```
powershell "C:\temp\Snap.ps1" 123 "c:\path\to\CSVfile.csv"
```